# Javascript Countdown Display in Php Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have a db table with several fields and i want to make a countdown with the integer value of one of the fields (as minutes). How can i loop and display the countdown of each of those rows in a php table using these values and adding or subtracting time in the process if I need to?

**Table.php**

```
            $sql="SELECT * FROM List where depName='Admisiones' and  personStatus='Espera'";
            $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            echo "<table border='15' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='3' bordercolor='00FF00'>
            <tr>
            <th>Turno</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Segundo Apellido</th>
            <th>Id Studiante</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Multiples Motivos</th>
            <th>Tiempo Categoria</th>
            <th>Tiempo Estimando</th>
            </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['listNum'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['personName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['personLast'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['secondLast'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['stuId'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['personStatus'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['manyMotive'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['categoryTime'] . "</td>";                                   
                echo "<td>" . $row['estimatedTime']"</td>"; //USE THE CLOCK.PHP TO MAKE A COUNTDOWN FOR EACH ESTIMATED TIME.
                //And have the ability to add or substrac time if needed.
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</table>";
```

**Clock.php**

```
      <script>
      $('.countdown').each(function(){
      var minutes = $(this).data('minutes');
      var count  = $(this); //countdown
      var id = $(this).id;
      $(this).countdown({
      date     :  Date.now() + (minutes * 60000),
      refresh  :  1000
      });

      setInterval(function(count)
      var minuteValue = count.text();
       $.ajax({
           url     : 'TEST.php', //I created to make the test..
           type    : 'POST',
           data    : {currentMin : minuteValue, id:id},
           success : function(response){
               console.log(response);
           }

          });
       });
    });
```

**TEST.php**

```
    <?php

    include 'Connection.php';
        $minValue =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,  $_POST['minuteValue']);
        $ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,  $_POST['id']);

        if (!$con) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $sql ="Update List SET estimatedTime='$minValue' WHERE listNum='$ID'";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. Can you post some code and clarify your problem?

Comment: I have everything i just need a way to implement it so the clock take the value from `$row['categoryTime']` and make a countdown in the `$row['estimatedTime']` row.

Comment: I don't know what's inside `$row['categoryTime']`, but if I understand your comment correctly, you need to pass it to your countDownTime function. So it would look like this: `<script>countDownTime(<?php echo $row['categoryTime']; ?>);</script>` and use that data to do countdown. I put script tag outside php tag but you can concat if easier. Still not 100% sure if I completely understand you tho.

Comment: Inside `$row['categoryTime']` is an number int like 30. But the script funtion dont have a parameter...i will work if I do it like that? If so can you give me an example as can I catch that var in the function.

Comment: Sorry for mi lack of knowledge its my first time with script. Can you help me mixing this two languages so it can work :)

Comment: OK, just tell me what does int 30 mean? Is that minutes? Is that start of the countdown? In your clock.php you are using hours, minutes, seconds for your countdown, but how is 'categoryTime' connected to that if you want to use it as countdown as you mentioned in your first comment

Comment: Table.php is a a big project i am working on. I find the clock.php online and copy paste it. It has no relation with mi php. I have a db table that with the loop and query fills my table. I want to use those integer numbers stored in the db to make my last field a countdown of that amount in minutes. The clock will know how to convert them. I want to use the categoryTime of each iteration to send it to the clock and make an object that will be placed in each row of the field of my online table .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's how I would do it. I would delete clock.php and use something more sophisticated. For example this js plugin:

http://rendro.github.io/countdown/

Download the file and include it in your `<head>` tag. Make sure you include jquery before that.

Inside your table.php change this line:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['estimatedTime']"</td>";
```

to:

```
echo "<td><div class=\'countdown\' data-minutes=\'{$row['categoryTime']}\' id=\{$row['id']'\'></div></td>";
```

Basically your html for that countdown field has to look like this (PS:30 is dynamic number coming from 'categoryTime') :

```
<td><div class="countdown" data-minutes="30" id="16"></div></td>
```

In footer of that page or in your javascript file include this script:

```
<script>
   $('.countdown').each(function(){
      var minutes = $(this).data('minutes');
      var id = $(this).id;
      $(this).countdown({
         date     :  Date.now() + (minutes * 60000),
         refresh  :  60000
      });

      var minuteValue = $(this).text();
      setInterval(function(){

           $.ajax({
               url     : 'url/to/php/file', //php file that updates your DB. Take the values from POST VAR.
               type    : 'POST',
               data    : {currentMin : minuteValue, id:id},
               success : function(response){
                   console.log(response);
               }

           });
      });
   });



</script>
```

With this, you will loop thru each .countdown element, get its minutes from data-minutes attr, and tell the countdown plugin when timer should expire by adding those minutes to Date.now() value.

**EDIT after your comment:**

What you are looking for is node.js. That would be perfect for you. But I've updated the code anyways. It is not tested so I don't know if that's gonna work. It should be something like that. The only issue could (MAYBE) be in setting interval for each row in your table.

**EDIT2**

- in php file, run query that updates rows in db
- depending on your DB, see if you can get number of rows affected
- if affected rows > 0, echo 1, otherwise echo 0
- in Firebug (or similar) check the console message to see output of your php or any other errors

This might help you find where the problem lies

Comment: Its working perfectly :D thanks. Now I want to know if there is a way every time the countdown refresh i can store the value in that field in the db?

Comment: I update the code too, i did what you say but it don't update.

Comment: see if you following those steps I mentioned above to try to find error

Comment: I find an error with the variables $_POST they both are empty. I use integer values to test it and the query works. The output of the console is this `<div class="countdown" data-minutes="10" id="1">00 hours, 07 min and 28 sec</div>` in the first row. In the second the id change to 2 and etc...

Comment: when looking at console you are only interested in what your php script returns back - wether 0 or 1. So do this to distinguish your console output: `console.log('PHP RESPONSE ==== ' + response);` and then look for that in console

Comment: `TypeError: count is undefined` This is what I found in the console.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake there. Try the code now....I removed any occurrence of the count and slightly different approach.

Comment: The console said that the `minValue` and `ID` values in `TEST.php` have an undefined index.